# variance of white noise generated by awgn matlab

Tags: matlab

I have try to add noise to a signal using awgn in matlab:

```
x % clean signal

x_noisy=awgn(x,10,'measured','db');
```

Can anybody tell me how to compute the standard deviation of the noise added here please?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like that?

```
x % clean signal
x_noisy=awgn(x,10,'measured','db');
standard_deviation_of_noise = std(x-x_noisy)
```

Comment: Thank you. In fact I can do this, but I am wondering is there any formula to compute sigma from the SNR?